# Android fails to retrieve the geolocation on a fresh install

Tags: android, cordova, angular, geolocation, ionic2

The first fresh install of my app on Android doesn't retrieve the Geolocation. **Android asks if I want to allow my location to be retrieved - I press 'Allow'.** If I close the app and re-open the app then location is retrieved and all works well. Please note this all works perfectly on iOS.

Options are:

```
let options = {enableHighAccuracy: false};
```

Geolocation has been setup correctly returning a promise.

[image]

Close and open app after this and it works as expected.

My manifest:

[image]

---

I have also tried with these options:

[image]

The catch is eventually executed.

[image]

Comment: It doesnt ask again if you press 'allow' and it is happening for marshmellow and above?

Comment: No it doesn't ask again after pressing 'allow', and yes marshmellow and above @suraj

Comment: Hope it clears i up

Answer (score 0):

It is completely expected behavior.
Android requires [Runtime Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) from marshmallow and above. Developers need to request permission from user even if it is defined in the manifest. Users can also disable permission later by going into settings.

For the **Geolocation plugin**, it seems to be handling this internally.

If your plugin does not show the dialog in the beginning, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282191/requesting-permissions-at-run-time-ionic) to specifically ask permission.

Comment: my dialog does show requesting to provide location, but after I press allow I still receive a geolocation timeout error. I have looked at the Diagnostic plugin but this won't fix my issue

Comment: timeout error would be unrelated to permissions.. have you tried kitkat version? or if the timeout still comes on second time. depends on your logs

Comment: the timeout still comes after calling a second time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859425/phonegap-geolocation-allways-fail-on-timeout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134548/discussion-between-joshua-nissenbaum-and-suraj).