# Android - when ever my app is installed, by default "No permission allowed" is set?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, phonegap-plugins

My app when-ever is installed via Google Play or USB 
(which use microphone, camera just like all other general app), by default the app gets "No permission allowed".

As a result it never works after the installation as fresh install.

Unless someone manually go in the app settings and change it.

[image]

What am i doing wrong? why its causing default into permission denied mode?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

**EDIT:**

```
C:\cordova\tpt>cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
Fetching plugin "cordova.plugins.diagnostic" via npm
Installing "cordova.plugins.diagnostic" for android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\tpt\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
null
org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:clean FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: C:\cordova\tpt\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.83 secs
Failed to install 'cordova.plugins.diagnostic':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\cordova\tpt\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: is the device OS Marshmallow and above? In code you need to handle runtime permission

Comment: check out my answer explaining the same...

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282191/requesting-permissions-at-run-time-ionic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set permissions for Marshmallow and above devices in code. Plugin provides this capability as well.

[Sample reference mentioning the same](http://www.qed42.com/blog/ionic-android-6-runtime-permissions) Even if it is mentioned for ionic, same methodology needs to be used in cordova projects

To get permission status , replicate like following.

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getPermissionAuthorizationStatus(function (status) {
  console.log(status);
  switch (status) {
    case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermissionStatus.GRANTED:
      //call the target method
      break;
    case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
      setPermission();
      break;
    case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermissionStatus.DENIED:
      setPermission();
      break;
    case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS:
      setPermission();
      break;
  }
}, this.errorCallback, cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
```

And to request authorization

```
function setPermission() {
  cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization(function (status) {
    switch (status) {
      case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
        break;
      case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
        break;
      case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
        //TODO : Call native plugin.
        break;
      case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED_WHEN_IN_USE:
        break;
    }
  }, function (error) { }, cordova.plugins.diagnostic.locationAuthorizationMode.ALWAYS);
}
```

Comment: Sir, i install the cordova plugin but failed, and when i tried your code in my index.html i do not get any alert triggers. Please kindly see my EDIT. i am using cordova 6.xx

Comment: If you can remove your android platform and add again. Then try adding necessary plugin's after this re-adding android platform.

Comment: And try with cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic.api-22 Go through this link    https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

Comment: Thank you. indeed it was Android 6.0.1 issue, where you need to use this great plugin. Thanks man !!!!!

Comment: @YumYumYum Glad to help. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android Marshmallow (6.0), you have to request the permissions at run-time. This way the user can manually accept or deny each permission you need.
For help on implementing permissions see the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

This prevents apps from 'secretly' using private device and user information without their consent.

Answer (score 0):

From Android M and further, you need to ask for runtime permission for each permissions needed.

An example of asking permission for CONTACTS will be :-

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

} else {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
 }
}
```

Comment: The question is about cordova and not native android

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24281403/ - If i try your JAVA code in Cordova it also failing to build/compile.