# ionic App doesn't ask permission for higher android version

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-permissions

I am using ionic to develop a mobile application. The application requires camera. I added Cordova camera plugin to my project. The application was working fine lower Android version but it not asking permission on higher than 6.0 Android .

Comment: this could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/36343809/2299040. Though you could have done some research

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility of olders plugins with devices >6.0  you can add one more plugin called cordova-plugin-compat.