# Saving file to Downloads directory using Ionic 3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

i know this link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#where-to-store-files

but i would like to save the file in Downloads directory. Is this possible to save the file in any path using Ionic? If so, please, share the example.

Here's the code:

```
downloadImage(image) {

this.platform.ready().then(() => {

  const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

  const imageLocation = `${cordova.file.applicationDirectory}www/assets/img/${image}`;

  fileTransfer.download(imageLocation, cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + image).then((entry) => {

    const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: `Download Succeeded!`,
      subTitle: `${image} was successfully downloaded to: ${entry.toURL()}`,
      buttons: ['Ok']
    });

    alertSuccess.present();

  }, (error) => {

    const alertFailure = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: `Download Failed!`,
      subTitle: `${image} was not successfully downloaded. Error code: ${error.code}`,
      buttons: ['Ok']
    });

    alertFailure.present();

  });

});

}
```

Basically I want save the file in location that is visible to the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem was lack of permission. Here is the working code that can download file to downloads directory:

```
async downloadFile() {
  await this.fileTransfer.download("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/23/21/soap-bubble-1959327_960_720.jpg", this.file.externalRootDirectory + 
  '/Download/' + "soap-bubble-1959327_960_720.jpg");
}

getPermission() {
  this.androidPermissions.hasPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    .then(status => {
      if (status.hasPermission) {
        this.downloadFile();
      } 
      else {
        this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
          .then(status => {
            if(status.hasPermission) {
              this.downloadFile();
            }
          });
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think the permission should be WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: How can I implement this with @ionic/vue  ? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To download the File to the Download directory you need to use Cordova **File** and **FileTransfer** Plugins.

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';

constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer) { }

fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

//Use your File Url and name

downloadFile(file) {
  // Some Loading
  this.fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.externalRootDirectory + 
  '/Download/' + file).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
  this.dismissLoading();
  this.presentToast('File has been downloaded to the Downloads folder. View 
  it..')
  })
  .catch(err => {
    this.dismissLoading();
    console.log(err)
  });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does this code really works for You? It doesn't for me. I can't save files in this directory. I am only able to save files in file.dataDirectory.

Comment: Yes it works and it saves the files in the Downloads directory. Have you installed ionic file plugin??

Comment: Yes I did, this code works for me but not when I try to save a file in file.externalRootDirectory. Does this file appear for a user in Download folder on a device?

Comment: Yes it appears in the Downloads directory i have tested this and implemented this code in my app.

Comment: I'm getting "Permission denied" exception. Have You ever experienced that?

Comment: Yes you are right this issue appears in the android 6 or greater. For this you need to ask the permission from the user at run time. This can be solved using **Android Permissions** plugins. Try this code on android version less than 6 and your file will be saved successfully.

Comment: Could You show me how to ask for the permission, please?

Comment: Please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143238/android-not-requesting-permission-in-ionic-app

Comment: Thank You for your help!

Comment: File-Transfer plugin is now deprecated. 
Use XMLHttpRequest() instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
constructor(private file: File, private transfer: FileTransfer){}

let link = 'url_to_download_file';
let path = '';
let dir_name = 'Download'; // directory to download - you can also create new directory
let file_name = 'file.txt'; //any file name you like

const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
let result = this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, dir_name, true);
result.then((resp) => {
  path = resp.toURL();
  console.log(path);
  fileTransfer.download(link, path + file_name).then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });
}, (err) => {
  console.log('error on creating path : ' + err);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but I've always had issues with the FileTransfer plugin. Maybe it is just me. I've instead had success with the `writeFile()` method of the File plugin.

I'm still working on iOS, but for Android here is what I have:

```
import { File } from "@ionic-native/file";

constructor(private fileSystem: File) {}
```

Then, in whatever function you have the logic to save the file, we have:

```
let path = this.fileSystem.externalRootDirectory + '/Download/'; // for Android
let filename = 'myNewFile.pdf';
this.fileSystem.writeFile(path, filename, File, { replace: true }).then(() => {
        this.toastCtrl.showToast('File has been downloaded. Please check your downloads folder.');
    }, (err) => {
        alert("Sorry. An error occurred downloading the file: " + err);
    }
);
```

As I said, I'm still looking out for what path to use for iOS. And I'm still wondering how to pop up the notification that usually comes up when a download actually goes to the download folder. But at least I am able to save directly in the download folder of Android.

Answer (score 1):

This code - ionic 3 capacitor - from josh morony takes a photo from the tmp directory and writes to the Document directory in this section using the FileSystem API the retrieves and manipulates the path

```
        Filesystem.writeFile({
            data: result.data,
            path: fileName,
            directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data
        })



getFromPhotos() {

  let options = {
  resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
  };

  Camera.getPhoto(options).then(

(photo) => {

    Filesystem.readFile({
        path: photo.path
    }).then((result) => {

        // let date = new Date(),
        // time = date.getTime(),
        time = 'bilder',
            fileName = time + '.jpeg';

        Filesystem.writeFile({
            data: result.data,
            path: fileName,
            directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data
        }).then((result) => {
            Filesystem.getUri({
                directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data,
                path: fileName
            }).then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
              let path = result.uri.replace('file://', '_capacitor_');
              this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(path);
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
}

);
```

}

In ionic 3 you have to use the cordova File plugin - please google. It is pretty straight forward to understand: you define the original directory where the file is, the original name of the file, the target directory, and a new name for the file inside that function. The principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

To download the File to the Download directory you need to use Cordova File Plugin:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';

constructor(
    private file: File,
  ) { }

this.file.writeFile(this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/Download/', user_log.xlsx, blob, { replace: true })
.then(() => {

              alert('File has been downloaded. Please check your downloads folder.')
    enter code here
            }, 
    (err) => {

              alert("Sorry. An error occurred downloading the file: " + err);
    enter code here
            });
          })
```

It works in Ionic 4 as well.