# Notifications dont work on SDK 33 Android 13 after upgrading from SDK 31

Tags: android, ionic-framework, notifications, android-notifications

With the playstore requiring the minimumTargetSDK version to be 33, it caused my notification libraries to no longer work with android 13.

**Libraries Affected**

```
 1. awesome-cordova-plugins/local-notifications/ngx (Local Notification)

 2. cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic/ngx (FCM)
```

**Attemped Solution**

Added necessary permission in Android Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

**Try to request for notification permission to no avail**

The former function will return false for requestPermission() without showing the dialog for me to indicate if I want to grant permission to the app.

```
async askForLocalNotificationPermission() {
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      const hasPermission = await this.localNotifications.requestPermission();

      if (hasPermission) {
        console.log('Notification permission granted');
      } else {
        console.log('Notification permission denied');
      }
    }
  }
```

The latter function will return true for requestPermission() without showing the dialog for me to indicate if I want to grant permission to the app.

```
async askForFCMNotificationPermission() {
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      const hasPermission = await this.fcm.requestPermission();

      if (hasPermission) {
        console.log('Notification permission granted');
      } else {
        console.log('Notification permission denied');
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further debugging,

I have discovered that the permissions libary was outdated and did not include the new permissions necessary for the sending of notification.

Hence the following steps were taking to resolve the issue

1. Update cordova-plugin-android-permissions
2. Update node_modules/@ionic-native/android-permissions/index.js
3. However as there arent any more recent updates for the android-permissions node module which contains the permission setting required to send notifications, **I had to manually add the permission into the index.js file.**

[image]

4. Add the following code to check and request for permission to send notification

   ```
   async askForNotificationPermission() {
    return new Promise((resolve)=> {
      let phoneVersion = parseInt(this.device.version, 10);
      if (phoneVersion >= 13) {
        this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.POST_NOTIFICATIONS).then(
            result => {
              if (result.hasPermission) {
                resolve(true);
              } else {
                // Request the permission
                this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.POST_NOTIFICATIONS).then(permission => {
                  if(permission.hasPermission) {
                  }
                  else{
                  }
                  resolve(true);
                });
              }
            },
            err => {
              console.error(err);
              resolve(true);
            }
        );
      }
    });
   ```

   }
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

Add this permission and request the user to grant the permission at runtime.

Comment: whats the code to request for notification at run time? I am finding it hard to ask for the permission in typescript as it is an ionic project.

Most of the example code is in java/kotlin

@Lathesh

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282191/requesting-permissions-at-run-time-ionic